# How does copy_to_bytes() behave on Chain?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

The documentation of [`copy_to_bytes()`](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.0.1/bytes/buf/trait.Buf.html#method.copy_to_bytes) says:

> Consumes `len` bytes inside `self` and returns new instance of Bytes with this data.
> This function may be optimized by the underlying type to avoid actual copies. For example, Bytes implementation will do a shallow copy (ref-count increment).

I wonder how `copy_to_bytes()` actually behaves when being applied on [`Chain`](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.0.1/bytes/buf/struct.Chain.html)? Does it copy both `Bytes`, or just one? Or does it just increase the ref-count?

```rust
use bytes::*;

fn main() {
    let slice1 = &[1,2,3];
    let slice2 = &[4,5,6];
    let a = Bytes::from_static(slice1);
    let b = Bytes::from_static(slice2);
    
    let chained = a.chain(b).copy_to_bytes(slice1.len() + slice2.len());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa0fe874b187c69bc2a075660943b500)

I also asked this question as an [issue on tokio-rs](https://github.com/tokio-rs/bytes/issues/491) but obtained no answer.

Comment: You can just look at the source: [`Chain` doesn't override `copy_to_bytes`](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.0.1/src/bytes/buf/chain.rs.html#132-174) so it gets the generic implementation (which copies the data over). I don't see how it could be otherwise either: the `chain` call can't just increase the refcount of the first bytes since it'd be missing the data from the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just treated as if they were **appended**.
As you pointed from the [documentation](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.0.1/bytes/buf/trait.Buf.html#method.copy_to_bytes):

> Consumes len bytes inside self and returns new instance of Bytes with
> this data.
>
> This function may be optimized by the underlying type to avoid actual
> copies. For example, Bytes implementation will do a shallow copy
> (ref-count increment).

So, yes, the values are copied into the bytes buffer.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=34ef355fe0ee5356d4d970c62b9ed091)

Comment: My Question was what exactly `appended` means, are both slices of memory just copied over to a new slice?

Comment: @YannickFunk, yes, the values are copied one by one into the buffer.